# Text is being clipped off inside Constraint Layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I use the below layout to achieve a view with image on the right end of a constraint layout, and a text to the left of the image:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout             
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"             
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                 android:layout_width="64dp"
                 android:layout_height="64dp"
                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                 android:background="#ff0000"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
 and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
 standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
 a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book"
                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
                 android:textColor="#000000"
                 android:textSize="20sp"/>
         </android.support.

constraint.ConstraintLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

I have attached the screenshot of the UI that has been obtained from above XML. The text is being clipped off on the left, when text is too long.

[Screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf4vO.png)

[Screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYoPR.png)

The dependency that is being used in build.gradle is:

**compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'**

Comment: add app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" to the TextView

Comment: What you need exactly?

Comment: @SrinivasKeerthiprakasam Below is the link of the expected output, that need to be achieved using Constraint Layout: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1IqmdOmqt3Tb2NIR1A2dFVSUkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try adding a padding of 8dp in TextView.

Comment: check your properties section, make sure the left constraint is 0 or any positive value for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with your fixed width and height on your imageView (`android:layout_width="64dp"` and `android:layout_height="64dp"`).

You can easily constraint you imageView using [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline)
 to give it size that relative to your screen.

All you need to do is fix your constraint :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragments.MenusDesign.ExpandableCategoriesMenu.ExpandableCategoriesMenu">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
 and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
 standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
 a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `LinearLayout` to `ConstraintLayout`.
Your Layout should like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
 and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
 standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
 a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Output:]

Comment: u shoudln't use a constraint layout in anohter constraint layout

Comment: why can I know the reason for that?

Comment: constraint layout is developed to have a flat layout design . flat layout have better performance in run time than hierarchy layout .u can just remove the first constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

Simply, add

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
```

*You can change the marginLeft as much as you want.